# Can't connect huawei p8 liteto on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, phone, huawei

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and am unable to read the files of my phone(huaweip8 lite) .My computer doesn't seem to read the device but my phone starts charging so the problem is not with the usb port.

Comment: Your post misses some important information that would help us finding a solution to your problem. Can you add the output of the following commands (when run from the Terminal) to your question: `lsusb` before and after plugging in the phone and `dmesg | tail` after plugging in the phone.

Comment: I'm just curious - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Developer options and Media transfer Protocol on the phone.
How to
http://www.syncios.com/android/how-to-debug-huawei-ascend-phone.html